# merging multiple files (html, css and js) with working links

Tags: javascript, html, css, file

I have multiple html files of different pages a css and a js file for my cv and im wondering how to combine them all to be able to add the as an attachment on indeed as it will only let me add 1 document, i need the links to be working to take to the different pages. Thanks

I've tried putting it all in one file but it all overlapped and I need it to be seperate pages.

Comment: [Welcome to StackOverflow](http://StackOverflow.com/tour) - Please read our [ask] page and edit your question to improve it.
Good questions tend to receive quick, better answers from the community.

Answer (score -1):

I found that, you can use a simple html tag :

```html
<div w3-include-html="your-page.html"></div>
```

Link your CSS file on the main page

If this doesn't works I think you can use `include()` with php but you need to install it :/

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow - please edit your answer and include new information as you see fit but having multiple answers on the same question is discouraged (unless there is a valid reason for it)

Comment: Thanks, yes I do :)

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding the question.  Original Post (OP) wants to have them attached to indeed (indeed.com) as one document.  Using PHP's  `include()`is not an option here (since it's not your server)

Comment: By itself, this does nothing. It's half of a system W3Schools cooked up, and requires [JavaScript to operate on the `[w3-include-html]` elements](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_html_include.asp).

Comment: Yeah ochis right i need it all in the 1 html file to be able to upload it as a cv to indeed